# Gui window Positioning in Autohotkey

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

In Autohotkey,

I want to position my Gui window to **right bottom** of the screen but how?

For illustrate,

```
+--------------------------------------+
|   Desktop (screen)                   |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                        +----------+  |
|                        |   Gui    |  |
|                        |  window  |  |
|                        |          |  |
|                        |          |  |
|                        +----------+  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: It's suitable for both sites frankly. It is a programming question. Kinda like how this site has tons of Powershell questions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use the pre-defined width and height of the GUI with the internal variables **A_ScreenWidth** and **A_ScreenHeight** and force Param2 of *Gui, Show* as an expression to make it work.  For example if the width of the GUI is 900 and the height is 550:

```
Gui, Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth - 900 " y" A_ScreenHeight - 550 " w" 900 " h" 550, The GUI
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using a tool build itself using the autohotkey.

This tool has a drag and drop support for positioning your controls according to your own liking.

Give it a try. You won't regret it. :)

No installation required, just run the file.

**[SmartGui](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic775.html)**

Comment: The OP was not asking about positioning controls, he was asking about positioning the whole GUI window relative to the screen. There is *nothing* in SmartGui that has anything to do with the screen or the window position.